# Get value from detailTextLabel after PickerInputViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a Custom cell that shows a pickerView when you select a row.
 Then you change the value and put it on detailTextLabel.
But this method get the value before it changes.

```
//Custom Cell


SimplePickerInputTableViewCell *cell = (SimplePickerInputTableViewCell *) [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier2];
                if (!cell) {
                    cell = [[SimplePickerInputTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier2];
                    UIImageView *lineView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-2, 45, 320, 10)];

                    lineView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"linha_horizontal.png"];
                    [cell addSubview:lineView2];

                    _opcaoTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 200, 20)];
                    _opcaoTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                    _opcaoTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    _opcaoTitle.text = @"Pista - Feminino";
                    [cell addSubview:_opcaoTitle];

                    _opcaoValueF = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 15, 100, 20)];
                    _opcaoValueF.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    [cell addSubview:_opcaoValueF];

                }
                _opcaoValueF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R$ %@,00", _eventFemininoValue];

                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
                [cell setValue:@"0"];

                return cell;


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSString *s = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] detailTextLabel] text];
    NSLog(@"String is: %@", s);

    int i = [s intValue];
    NSLog(@"This is the int value: %d", i);
}
```

**SimplePicker.m**

```
#import "SimplePickerInputTableViewCell.h"

@implementation SimplePickerInputTableViewCell

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize value;

__strong NSArray *values = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", nil];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setValue:(NSString *)v {

    value = v;
    self.detailTextLabel.text = value;
    self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (![value isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [self.picker selectRow:[values indexOfObject:value] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }

    _backgroundValue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(285, 3, 40, 40)];
    _backgroundValue.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon_popular.png"];
    [self addSubview:_backgroundValue];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:_backgroundValue];

   }



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [values count];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [values objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 44.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 300.0f; //pickerView.bounds.size.width - 20.0f;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.value = [values objectAtIndex:row];

    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableViewCell:didEndEditingWithValue:)]) {
        [delegate tableViewCell:self didEndEditingWithValue:self.value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the value as soon as the new cell is created (the cell is probably not even drawn on the screen at this time). To solve this you should capture the value when the use dismisses the picker view.

From the additional code you provided

1) Set up a delegate for the table view cell:

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

You can do this right after you create it

2) Add an implementation of `tableViewCell:didEndEditingWithValue:`

```
- (void)tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell didEndEditingWithValue:(NSValue*)value
{
    NSLog(@"Value is %@", value);
}
```

Comment: I know it, the problem is that I dont know how to get the value after picker view dismiss.

Comment: How/when are you dismissing the picker? You have not provided code for that; perhaps post the code for `SimplePickerInputTableCellView`.

Comment: I just have post the code for SimplePickerInputTableCellView. thx

Comment: So you need to set your table view controller as the delegate for your `SimplePicketInputTableCellView` and implement `tableViewCell:didEndEditingWithValue:`. This will be called when the user has chosen a value.

Comment: cell.delegate = self, gives me the following error and do not work: Assigning to 'id<SimplePickerInputTableViewCellDelegate>' from incompatible type 'BuyoutViewController *const __strong'

Comment: Your BuyoutViewController must conform to the SimplePickerInputTableViewCellDelegate protocol. So somewhere you have  `@class BuyoutViewController : UITableViewController` it needs to be `@class BuyoutViewController : UITableViewController<SimplePickerInputTableViewCell>`. But seriously, if you are having this much trouble it is time to go read some tutorials. You're obviously not that familiar with Objective C and UIKit.

Comment: Yeah, I just have 2 months learning objective-C, thx it now works.

Comment: No worries, just that spending some time learning the basics about Objective C and common idioms (like the use of delegates) will spare you a lot of a grief. Glad you got it working ;-)